# Using a variable from a different window

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window in JavaScript, and show some data from the opener window. Based on something I read I made this:

MainWindow.html

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function OpenNewWindow()
{
    this.MainWindowData = 123123;
    document.write(this.MainWindowData);

    var wnd = window.open("NewWindow.html");
    wnd.NewWindowData = 787878;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="OpenNewWindow()">
</body>

</html>
```

NewWindow.html:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function ShowData()
{
    document.write("NewWindowData: " + this.NewWindowData + "<br />");
    document.write("MainWindowData: " + window.opener.MainWindowData);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Show Data" onclick="ShowData()">
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that both variables remain undefined.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you not use a querystring parameter?

Comment: Did you try use top.opener or take "window" (before opener) off?

Comment: @Fred: I don't want to make anything, just tried this. I think it would be good too, but I'm just curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: @ViniciusLima: I don't know what do you mean

Comment: @ViniciusLima: Since `opener` is a global variable, it's a property of the global object (`window`). So unless you have another variable shadowing it, `opener` and `window.opener` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the variables you're creating, it's that `document.write` wipes out the window's content when you call it any time except during initial rendering, and so wipes out the variables you're creating after you create them. So you don't want to use it after initial rendering.

If you change your `document.write` calls to (say) `document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = ...;` or you use `document.createElement`, you'll get more successful results.

Here are your pages, just changing `document.write` to using `document.createElement`, which makes them work.

Main window: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/avemaw/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/avemaw/1/edit)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function OpenNewWindow()
{
    this.MainWindowData = 123123;

    var wnd = window.open("http://jsbin.com/uvocos/1");
    wnd.NewWindowData = 787878;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="OpenNewWindow()">
</body>

</html>
```

Popup window:  [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uvocos/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uvocos/1/edit)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ShowData()
{
    display("NewWindowData: " + this.NewWindowData);
    display("MainWindowData: " + window.opener.MainWindowData);
}

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p)
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Show Data" onclick="ShowData()">
</body>

</html>
```

The `createElement` is in the `display` function I added to the popup.

Separately: I would probably use `window` rather than `this` to create the variable. `this` will actually **be** `window` the way you're calling your functions, so it works, but there are other ways to call functions where it wouldn't work, and using `window.foo = ...;` would.

Finally: I'm not certain that your putting a variable on the popup **immediately** after opening it (your `NewWindowData`) will work reliably, although it does in the above (for me). Usually rather than that, I have the popup pull the data from the opener (your `MainWindowData` variable) and/or pass the data to the popup via the query string.

Comment: It's simply not related at all to the initial question

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas: Yes, it is. In fact, it's the crux of the question: The OP's code is *wiping out* the window, and the variable thereon. Look at the corrected example I posted. All I changed was how the information is output, switching from `document.write` to DOM methods. Et voila, the variables are fine.

Comment: i will agree with @T.J. Crowder. The only way i manage to make it work was by changing `document.write` with `console.log`. No other change.

Comment: if I only change that, it still writes out undefined to the console

Comment: @KocsisDávid: You're not writing to the console at all in your quoted code. Again, the above works. Try clicking [the "Live Copy" link](http://jsbin.com/avemaw/1) on the main window, clicking the "Open Window" button, and clicking the "Show Data" button in the resulting window. You see the two variables (on Chrome, on Firefox, on IE...). Just for fun I fired up a VM with IE6, even works there.

Comment: okey, If I click to the Live Copy it works, but if I paste it to files in HDD, it crashes in IE 9, in Chrome I get undefined, in Firefox it works.

Comment: @KocsisDávid: Opening HTML files from your hard drive (`file://` URLs) is a very different thing from opening them in the normal way (`http://` or `https://` URLs). In particular, some browsers disallow all cross-window access in files opened locally, blocking access because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), even though they come from the same place on your local hard drive. In general, don't use local files to test web development, always open via a server. :-) (If you look in the JS console, you'll see an access error.)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is actually pretty close but using `this.` is probably causing issues.

In the parent window, use:

```
var newWindowVariable = 'Something';
```

In the new window, use:

```
var myVariable = window.opener.newWindowVariable;
```

This is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: The way the functions are being called, using `this` is fine. But I agree it's not ideal.

Comment: can you make the whole two file? because it don't want to work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage.

```
 /* Page A */
  window.localStorage.setItem("NewWindowData ", "787878");

  /* Page B */
  var stringValue = window.localStorage.getItem("NewWindowData");
```

Then you can convert to int, or whatever you want to cast it to.

Comment: Very browser dependent, won't work in IE7 which is still a large part of the market.

Comment: Not IE7, but IE9 & 10 it works. IE7 is slowly losing market share, but it's a slow process. IE has always been the redheaded stepchild in jQuery, javascript compatibility and standards.

Comment: Should work in IE8 too theoretically. Microsoft took a while to come around to the idea of accepting and following standards but IE10 is a good step in the right direction.

Comment: Agreed. I can't tell you the number of times I've had something working in Firefox and Chrome, only to have it busted in IE.

Comment: There is no reason to use local storage for this. Sharing variables between pages in the way the OP is has lots of utility, and is universally compatible. The problem is the `document.write`, not the variables.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't either, but for our user's purposes it may fit. I was proposing an alternative solution to the ones up here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value from your parent window you can use in the popup window.

```
 window.opener.document.getElementById('idOfelement').value
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/ujaqis/1)

Comment: Yes it should. You have get the value of any element using the Id